# Gather usernames in instagram

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

the main problem is i want to gather and get usernames of who liked my posts, who saw my story and ...

when i have list of these usernames, i can understand who is ghost in my followers and who is loyal to me and ....

i wrote something with `selenium` , it would login to Instagram. but i can't and i don't know how to save any username in it. any idea?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CMAVjR5CmOx/')

c2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/a")
c2.click()

c3 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div").text
print(c3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to login:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CMAVjR5CmOx/')
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF").click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("username")
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password"+Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: i know how to login, the problem is i want to get usernames after logging in

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to know which information (elements) you want to target.
Then you need to write better xpaths. You can learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

you want them concise and not as brittle as the ones you've specified.
Like this to click on the liked by button:

```
//a[contains(@href,'liked_by')]
```

and then this to grab all the dialog container:

```
//div[@role='dialog']
```